# How to solve the error related to UTF-8 characters on new Lenovo (Windows 11 - R version 4.3.1)

Tags: r, tidy, broom, polish

I am obtaining an error which I do not how to solve

```
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `term = stringr::str_trim(term)`.
Caused by error in `stri_trim_both()`:
! invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected; try calling stri_enc_toutf8()
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The code I have written down uses the `tidy()` function on a series of models with polish character. To enable the reading of those characters I have used the following code

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Polish")
```

and then:

```
list_of_fitting[['anova']] = lapply(list_of_fitting[['anova']], function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y) tidy(y) %>% mutate(term = str_replace_all(
    term, c('rsptsk'='Taskresp','Płeć'='Gender', ":" = "*")))))
```

Can anyone suggest something? Specifically since on my last PC (having Windows 10 an operative system and R version 4.1.1, downloaded both as 32 or 64 bits, while here I have just the one with 64 bits) do you possibly think that it is due on the lack of this 32 bits version? Has anyone did something else on Windows 11?

Thanks

Comment: `stri_enc_toutf8()` didn't help, did it?

Comment: Well, in case that is the code to use, actually I did not understand where to put it? Should I use it as an isolated/normal code row before the `lapply code`?

Comment: Put it where the error warning advises: `Caused by error in ...`. That suggests `mutate(term = str_replace_all(stri_enc_toutf8(term), c('rsptsk'='Taskresp','Płeć'='Gender', ":" = "*")))`, although it might be necessary to UTF-encode "Płeć", too.

Comment: Indeed, I have tried what yoou suggested but dooes not seem to work. How can I encode UTF-encode "Płeć"?

Comment: From another machine, perhaps OS and locale (country setting) I'm afraid I can't further. Now the issue has turned out to be (probably) UTF-related, you might want to explore https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+UTF-8 for existing solutions though.

Comment: ok, thanks. I have just tried to add more detail since on my last laptop I did not have this issue.